# how can add photos from flickr?

Tags: java

I would like to know how can i add photos from flickr by giving desired username into my application.Username is the input given by the user and on clicking the button photos of desired user gets open. Please help me out of this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many things to consider here. First, read the documentation of the [Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/), especially the REST API. Through a REST Request (which is a normal HTTP request), you can receive pretty much everything from Flickr as an XML response, which again you can parse.

Google has [implemented a Flickr Client](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Photostream/src/com/google/android/photostream/Flickr.java) in one of their demo apps.

You would probably use the `findByUsername` function to receive a Flickr user and then search for all his photos.

You can get the photos by combining their URL from the Server, Farm and Photo-ID information and download them by Java.

Btw: You should maybe include your skill level with Java, Android and REST services in general to receive more helpful answers. Also, be a little more specific in what exactly you want. The information about photos? The photos themselves?

Comment: i would to have photos themselves shown in application in a grid

Comment: Alright. I added Google's Flickr Client in my original answer above, you might find that helpful. You still haven't said where exactly your problem lies (the API calls, parsing the responses, getting the photos, showing them in the grid,...)